# Db2 XML insertion into XML datatype columns

Tags: db2, db2-400

How to insert these into columns in db2.

Columns are:
(dept_id integer,
text_xml XML)

Insert into xml_test values(1,'1000010)

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper XML if you want to insert it into XML column. "'1000010" is not a string that can be interpreted as valid XML.

I don't have iSeries handy, but with LUW and table like this:

```
db2 "create table xmltest(c1 int, c2 xml)"
```

you can either insert XML as string:

```
$ db2 "insert into xmltest values (1, '<name> db2inst1 </name>')"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

or e.g. with XMLPARSE:

```
db2 "insert into xmltest values (2, XMLPARSE(document '<name> db2inst1 </name>') )"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

Comment: In c2  column,is possible to add <name>db2inst2</name><dept>inst2</dept> like this.?

Comment: A valid XML value could be as follows: `xmlparse (document '<doc><name>db2inst2</name><dept>inst2</dept></doc>')`